# boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator Check if values are null

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I've got a block of code that throws an Access Violation when executed. It is the async_connect handler for boost::asio.

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void MyClient::OnConnect(const boost::system::error_code & errorCode, boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint)
{
    if (errorCode || endpoint == boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator())
    {
        // Error - An error occured while attempting to connect
        // Most likely these error codes correspond to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668(v=vs.85).aspx
        std::ostringstream msg;
        msg << "An error occured while attempting to connect to " << endpoint->host_name()
            << ". Error code: " << errorCode
            << ". Error Message: " << ErrorCodeToString(errorCode);

        LogError(msg.str().c_str(), __FUNCSIG__, __FILE__, __LINE__);
        return;
    }

    // We connected to an endpoint
    m_connectionState |= CONNECTED;
```

In the debugger it looks like the problem is inside endpoint->host_name(), because it tried to get values_[0] while values_ are null.

This is a common Connection Refused scenario. I thought the handler got the endpoint so that it knew who it was trying to connect to! Is there some manner of check I can do on the iterator before I try to call a method on it?

It seems to pass and still throw access violation on

```
if( endpoint != boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator() )
{
    std::string blah = endpoint->host_name();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you've figured this out by now, but I'll post a few lines in case someone else happens upon it.

This problem looks similar to one I had.

This will **not** work, and will give similar results to what you're describing.

```
 void establish_connection() {
      tcp::resolver resolver(get_asio_io_service());  // this is a problem      
      tcp::resolver::query q{server_name, "https"};
      resolver.async_resolve(q,
                             [&](asio::error_code ec,
                                 tcp::resolver::iterator it) {
                                this->handle_resolve(ec, it);
                             });
   }
```

where establish_connection() is a method in the object that deals with communication to the server.

The resolver object disappears after the establish_connection() exits.  You have to find a way to make it stick around.  The various demos on the web have it as an attribute of the client object.

Please share your experience with this problem.